# Setting "Apply local firewall rules" on public profile makes Windows Firewall drop all connections

Tags: windows, security, firewall

I've been tasked with securing our server as per [CIS recommendations](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/), and one of those recommendations is to set "Apply local firewall rules" to no on the public profile of the Windows Firewall.

However, we use RDP to connect to this server, and configuring that setting causes both the webserver (IIS) and the RDP connections to drop. This is despite the fact that the following rules are set to Allow:

1. Remote Desktop - Shadow (TCP-In)
2. Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)
3. Remote Desktop - User Mode (UDP-In)
4. World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)
5. World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In)

What could be the reason these services are blocked?

EDIT: Log looks like so:

```
[time] DROP TCP [ip] [ip] 11818 80 52 S 2874034315 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're not using the correct profile.  You may be on a Private or Domain profile instead of Public.  Be sure the Firewall rules are enabled on the profile you're using otherwise they're not going to work.

Comment: I checked, and the "active" profile is the public one. All mentioned rules are enabled on all profiles.

Comment: Does that mean you're not domain joined?  If that's the case, enabling the "Apply local firewall rules" would ignore the rules you added since that's the point of that setting